# XCAssets PNG White Space

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, xcasset

I'm making some animation in Swift/SpriteKit

I have an image with a transparent background.
The image canvas itself is 250 x 250, and inside there is an image of a ball that is about 100x100 (So it's an image of a 100x100 ball surrounded by transparency such that the entire canvas/image is 250x250)

When I drag and drop this PNG into xcassets to create an image, the ball appears smaller.

If I took the same ball (just the 100x100 image, no transparency around it) and dragged&dropped to create a different image, that new image seems bigger and the ball looks better.

Is the transparency messing with this?
Any ideas why that would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the asset catalog, Xcode tries to fit the whole of your image into this space:

[image]

Let's assume that space is 150x150 in size. To fit your 250x250 image into there, Xcode needs to resize your image by a scale factor of 0.6. The ball was originally 100x100. After the resizing, it appears to be 60x60 on screen (but the ball is still 100x100 in actuality through).

Your 100x100 image with only the ball on the other hand, needs to be resized by a scale factor of 1.5. Your ball appears to be 150x150 after the resize. This is why it looks bigger.

The same thing happens when you try to put these images into a `UIImageView`.

But if you use these two images as the textures for sprites, the balls will both appear to be 100x100 on screen. This is because the sprites' sizes will automatically adjust to fit the size of the textures without you doing anything.

Comment: ok thanks this is hugely helpful but i'm still a little confused; what should I do for the few images I have (I have a few images of different sizes and different canvas sizes) that i'm all putting in the 3x slot. What formula should I apply? Is there a correlation between the transparency/canvas size and the image?

Comment: @NullHypothesis 1x should be the original image. The 2x image should have double the width and height of the original. The 3x image should have triple the width and height of the original. It's simple as that. The OS will choose which image to use depending on the device. You don't need to do anything extra. The transparency is just part of the image.

Comment: oh that hugely clarifies it, thanks. So just to recap to make sure I understand:  without transparency, my ball should be 100@3x, 66@2x, and 33@1x, but now that i'm adding transparency to those images, I want to take my 250x250 (which I originally thought was 3x) and make that my new 1x Then multiple accordingly (*2 and *3) to get the new @2x and @3x? Thus it's 250@1x, 500@2x, and 750@3x) right?

Comment: @NullHypothesis Your ball's size should be directly proportional to the image's size. I suggest you to use 100x100 sized images with 100x100 sized balls for 1x, 200x200 for 2x and 300x300 for 3x.

Comment: I used the ball/100/250 sizes above as an example but it's actually a person of 465x642 that is on a canvas of 882x667. 882x667 so I can use a fixed image size to prevent the person from warping as I play each frame of him doing something.  So based on this new information what "formula" can I apply to this?  I.e. if my person is 465 x 642 in frame #1, and he's 550 x 642 in frame #4 (because his hands are outstretched) then my thought was as long as he's on a background of the max width/height that any frame consumes, then his animation is smooth (no warping). So what dimensions should I use?

Comment: @NullHypothesis give all your textures a size of x by y such that x > x_n and y > y_n for any value of n where x_n and y_n is the width and height of the person in frame #n.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136793/discussion-between-nullhypothesis-and-sweeper).